# For $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ closed, show that $\frac{d(x, K)}{1 + d(x,K)} \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed. Let

$$d(x,K) := \text{dist}(x,K) = \inf_{k \in K}\|x - k\|$$

be the distance function from a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to the set $K$.

> Show that the function $G(x) = \frac{d(x, K)}{1 + d(x,K)} \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n).$

This claim is part of the proof of Theorem 2 from section 3.1 in Perko's *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems.* This claim is plausible to me, but I'm not exactly sure how to prove it. Of course, we can try to prove the claim by finding an explicit formula for the partial derivatives

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{G(x + he_j) - G(x)}{h} = \cdots .$$

But it seems like this calculation could get messy very quickly. I am also worried that this claim may not be true in general. For instance, what if the boundary of $K$ is very rough. Is $G(x)$ still $C^1$ in that case?

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recall that there is (quite involved) paper of Philp (?) Hartmann from the 50's where he investigates the case that $K$ is a regular plain curve. There is also a paper of Brian White from the 90's on a similar question. The result is something to the end that almost all real values are regular values of the distance function, but that differentiability breaks down in focal points and cut locus. It's been a while and I don't recall the details, but in general it's quite a difficult question. I second the proposal that convexity of $K$ will be helpful, but I guess $C^1$ might be needed, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly false. Take $n=1$ and $K=\{0\}$. You get $$G=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|},$$which is not differentiable at the origin.

**Edit:** No, $G$ need not be smooth in the complement of $K$ either. Take $n=1$ and $K=\{-1,1\}$; then $G$ is not differentiable at $0$.

**Edit:** Otoh $G$ is $C^1$ in the complement of $K$ if $K$ is convex. In fact $d(x,K)$ is.

Write $x=(t,y)$ with $t\in\Bbb R$ and $y\in \Bbb R^{n-1}$. Choose coordinates so $p=(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ is the point of $K$ closest to $p$.

Convexity shows that $\{(0,0)\}\subset K\subset\{t\le 0\}$, hence near $p$ we have $$t^2\le d((t,y),K)^2\le t^2+|y|^2.$$ So $d^2$ is differentiable at $p$, with gradient $(1,0)$.

**Edit:** I was taking the continuity of the derivative as clear; maybe it's not. A cheap way to show it's continuous:

Say $k(p)$ is the point of $K$ closest to $p$ (note that $K$ convex implies that $p(k)$ is unique). If you undo the "choose coordinates such that..." you see that the gradient of $d^2$ at $p$ is $$\frac{p-k(p)}{||p-k(p)||}.$$(Or if you don't see that it doesn't really matter, it's clear that the argument above shows that the gradient is given by *some* gizmo in terms of $p$ and $k(p)$.) So it's enough to show that $k(p)$ depends continuously on $p$.

Say $p_n\to p$. Now $k(p_n)$ is certainly bounded, so if $k(p_n)$ does not converge to $k(p)$ there is a subsequence converging to something else; relabelling, we have $k(p_n)\to k_0\ne k(p)$. Now $d(x)=d(x,K)$ is certainly continuous, so $$||p-k_0||=\lim||p_n-k(p_n)||=\lim d(p_n)=d(p)=||p-k(p)||,$$contradicting the uniqueness of $k(p)$.

Comment: This example is convincing to me. What if we restrict $G(x)$ to the complement of $K$? Would $G$ be smooth there? I will try to check that.

Comment: @JZShapiro Restricting to the complement of $K$ won't help, either. If $K$ is, e.g,  the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then the distance function will fail to be differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @JZShapiro No. See edit

Comment: Darn, this is unfortunate. I don't think I am misinterpreting what Perko writes is his proof either. He very clearly writes $G(x) \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $K$ can be any closed set. I will have to figure out if the proof can be salvaged. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @JZShapiro I'd suspect that maybe $G$ is $C^1$ in the complement of $K$ if $K$ is convex; maybe one needs some smoothness of the boundary as well.

Comment: @JZShapiro Yes, convexity is enough to get $C^1$  in the complement of $K$. See edit

Comment: What you have shown at the end of you answer shows that certain directional derivatives exist. How does this imply that $d$ is of class $C^1$?

Comment: @Thomas Actually it shows that $d^2$ is _differentiable_, which is more than the existence of directional derivatives. Anyway, continuity is proved in the latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any additional assumptions on $K$? Otherwise I doubt this is true. Look for example at $n=2$ and $K:=\{x=(x_1,x_2): -1\le x_i \le 1\}$, a square. Along the upper boundary the gradient of $d(x, K)$ is just the vector $(0,1)$, along the right hand side boundary its $(1,0)$. This won't be continous at the upper right corner of $K$. The denominator won't help much here. (Am I missing anything here?)